# Java Single Sign On implementation with JOSSO using WAS6.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, josso

I want to implement Single Sign On(SSO) in java web application using JOSSO library.Can anybody help me because I don't hava idea that how to implement it.
Thanks..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for what constitutes a question here.

Answer (score 0):

There's tons of documentation for configuring SSO on the IBM web site.  For example:

- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Fcsec_sso.html
- http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/REDP4192.html?Open

However, I don't know if JOSSO supports Websphere.  It didn't used to; you'll have to ask on the Josso home page and/or user forums to get more information.